# HPROF result interpretation

Tags: java, scala, file-io, hprof, space-efficiency

I have two sets of HProf dumps one for large sample and other for smaller sample - both are result from a very small sample of the huge data that I have. I'm trying to figure out the bottleneck in my approach.

Here are my Heap allocation data for Large (http://pastebin.com/PEH8yR3v) and small sample (http://pastebin.com/aR8ywkDH).

I notice that char[] is the one that takes most of my memory.Also the % of memory takaen by char[] varies from small to large sample run. I don't know how it will vary when I profile my whole sample.

But, the important question I'm concerned is - with this program( READ, PARSE/PROCESS ,WRITE) when I try to run for a input data of size of 3GB which writes back 10GB of data. Except for a   list whose size is not more than 1GB, I'dont store anything in memory - this is plain read, process, write pipeline. Given this, my program still takes around 7GB of main memory while running.

This is my approach,

```
read a file in from a string Iterator
for each line in ip_file perform 
  op_buffer = myFunction(line)
write op_buffer to op_file.
Perform this for all 20K files in my input data. 

def myFunction(line)
{
 var :String = null;
 for each word in line  
  {
   var class_obj = new Classname(word)
   op_line + = class_obj.result
  }
return op_line
}
```

Since, the objects created inside the myFunction will scope out at the end of myFunction, I don't take care to delete/free them. Do you guys sense any  bottlenecks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since, the objects created inside the myFunction will scope out at the end of myFunction

No, they won't. This is not C++. All objects are created on the heap and remain in existence until garbage collectible.

Also, you haven't declared `op_line` anywhere in your pseudocode, so I assume it is being retained between method calls, and I guess that is your memory leak. I mean there is no way you should have *a single character array* consisting of > 100 million bytes, which is what the "small" heap dump says you have.

Comment: Oh thanks for noticing it. I have declared it inside th function. Edited it. Now, so even if the `class_obj` is not  accessible outside the `myFunction`, it will stay in memory (HEAP) untill my program completes ? Now, this explains why my memory grows for a simple read and write.In C++, I can  call destructor/free. In Java / scala, What is the best way to delete/free `class_obj` from memory at  end of the myFunction ?

Comment: No, if it's not accessible it is garbage collectible, so that's not the issue. The biggest issue is, as I said, the enormous 100MB character array object (which might be the backing array for a `String`).

Comment: Yes, you are right that will be garbage collected but a clean way would be to delete/free them once I'm done with `class_obj` right, that is why I would like to know. Also  I would assume that comes from my setting of 100MB buffersize for BufferWriter. Again is this is big concern  - will this grow in memory slowing down my operation ?

Comment: Oh, so that's a fixed buffer size. That is not an issue then either. For garbage collection, you can ask the JVM to do it right now instead of later, but that's not very elegant, and usually not necessary. The important thing is to avoid the use of swap space, because that really slows things down - so set your `-Xmx` JVM option appropriately.

Comment: Yes, a fixed buffer for writing big op file of size around 900MB.I have 8 GB RAM, So I use `java -Xmx7g MyJar.jar`, so that my program uses the max possible memory for its Heap. Should this be okay ?

Comment: I don't know, it might depend on the operating system and its configuration (e.g. swappiness). Linux by default uses about half of its RAM for cache and buffers, I think.

Comment: Oh thanks @Robin Green. I guess I need to read up on that.But, seeems to me that, the object being deleted problem is not a big problem as I found it to be.

Comment: @Learner: Really cool! A buffer size 100MB might make sense... in 20 years maybe. Once I measured what buffer size is best and it was something like 64kB whereby 8kB was nearly equally good. A bigger buffer doesn't help at all unless you're doing something extremely special with some futuristic device.

Comment: Ha! I'm writing a 2GB file, so hence instead of writing line by line(4 Million), I thought I will write as 100MB blocks. I figured that sounds like a very  weird option. Maybe, I will switch to 64KB.